# Updates to a Table | Impala | SQL | Hadoop

Tags: sql, hadoop, sql-update, impala

I have tables build on Hadoop. These are impala tables. (Not Kudu).

Issue : I have to update the few cols values (eg: load_date,fraud_type) from ulti_up_2 table  for a set of keys (dw,auth,ulti_date) in the final_up_2 table.

I have the below mentioned used case :-
Table 1 :

```
create table dbo.ulti_up_2 (
   dw string
   ,auth int
   ,ulti_date string
   ,load_date string
   ,fraud_type string
),
```

```
insert into dbo.ulti_up_2  
values ('b',1,'2021-07-25','2021-07-27','x'),
('c',0,'2021-07-25','2021-07-27','y');

Table 2:
create table dbo.final_up_2 (id int,auth_date string,dw string,auth int,ulti_date string,load_date string,fraud_type string)

insert into dbo.final_up_2 values 
(1,'2021-07-24','a',1,'2021-07-25','2021-07-25','p'),
(2,'2021-07-24','b',1,'2021-07-25','2021-07-25','q'),
(3,'2021-07-24','c',0,'2021-07-25','2021-07-25','t'),
(4,'2021-07-24','d',1,'2021-07-25','2021-07-25','r');

create table dbo.refresh_table1 as 
select df_prep.id,df_prep.auth_date,df_prep.dw,df_prep.auth,df_prep.ulti_date,
ulti_prep.fraud_type,ulti_prep.load_date 
from dbo.final_up_2 df_prep 
left join 
dbo.ulti_up_2 ulti_prep 
on df_prep.dw=ulti_prep.dw and 
df_prep.auth=ulti_prep.auth and 
df_prep.ulti_date=ulti_prep.ulti_date;

Output Coming :
id|auth_date|dw|auth|ulti_date|fraud_type|load_date
(1,'2021-07-24','a',1,'2021-07-25',NULL,NULL),
(2,'2021-07-24','b',1,'2021-07-25','x','2021-07-27'),
(3,'2021-07-24','c',0,'2021-07-25','y','2021-07-27'),
(4,'2021-07-24','d',1,'2021-07-25',NULL,NULL);

Output I need :
id|auth_date|dw|auth|ulti_date|fraud_type|load_date
(1,'2021-07-24','a',1,'2021-07-25','p','2021-07-25'),
(2,'2021-07-24','b',1,'2021-07-25','x','2021-07-27'),
(3,'2021-07-24','c',0,'2021-07-25','y','2021-07-27'),
(4,'2021-07-24','d',1,'2021-07-25','r','2021-07-25');

Thanks in Advance. Please Help.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the left join with `ulti_up_2` is failing for some cases. if you handle them, you should get data.

```
create table dbo.refresh_table1 as 
select df_prep.id,df_prep.auth_date,df_prep.dw,df_prep.auth,df_prep.ulti_date,
ifnull(ulti_prep.fraud_type,df_prep.fraud_type) as fraud_type , --This will fetch data from final_up_2 in case left join fails.
ifnull(ulti_prep.load_date,df_prep.load_date) as load_date  --This will fetch data from final_up_2 in case left join fails.
from dbo.final_up_2 df_prep 
left join 
dbo.ulti_up_2 ulti_prep 
on df_prep.dw=ulti_prep.dw and 
df_prep.auth=ulti_prep.auth and 
df_prep.ulti_date=ulti_prep.ulti_date;
```